# Ruby find like string array from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, search

Say that I have three arrays `arr1`, `arr1` and `arr3`.

```
arr1 = ["apple", "book", "car", "dog"]
arr2 = ["apple", "book"]
arr3 = ["app", "boo"]
```

How can I check if `arr1` includes: `arr2`, and `arr3` with like wildcards.

Comment: Can you edit You answer with some examples, supply some example input and what You expect on output.

Comment: What I meant is to check if both arr2 and arr3 is in arr1.

Comment: @hudadiaz you actually want to check if all of `arr2`'s *elements* are included in `arr1` or if all of `arr3`'s *patterns* are found in `arr1`.

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
arr3.all? { |item| arr2.grep(/#{item}/)[0] }
#=> true
```

This matches substrings (e.g. `ook`), to match only prefixes use `/^#{item}/`.

Comment: `grep` returns an array.

Comment: yes.. i know..i am checking why the first element you are checking? :) why not `Array#empty?` ?

Comment: Just because it's a bit shorter :)